# Unable to access input from the label that is its parent with dom-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I found myself having trouble trying to access an input from the label, when the label wraps around the input. It looked like an easy problem to solve, but I'm having a heck of a time.

```
<label htmlFor="termsAgreement">
    <input type="checkbox" name="termsAgreement"/>
    <p>Here are the terms of use</p>
</label>
```

I was thinking that the following would work, but had no luck:

```
getByLabelText('Here are the terms of use', {selector: 'input'});
```

A small example snippet with a couple tests could be found here:

[react-testing-library demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/qqpy2z13yw?module=%2Fsrc%2Fexample.test.js&previewwindow=tests)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was using the `name` field rather than the intended `id` field to locate the associated input.